# Interpolate then extrapolate boundary values

Tags: pandas, numpy, scipy, interpolation

The following program doesn't interpolate the value at 0,7

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([np.nan, 2, 4,np.nan, 8, np.nan], [0,1,2,4,5,7])
interp = s.interpolate(method='akima', order=2)
print(s)
print(interp)

0    NaN
1    2.0
2    4.0
4    NaN
5    8.0
7    NaN
dtype: float64
0         NaN
1    2.000000
2    4.000000
4    6.888889
5    8.000000
7         NaN
dtype: float64
```

How do I get the values at 0 and 7? Extrapolation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it depends, because every interpolation method works in a different way. 
If you are ok with using the `spline` / `pchip` / `linear` methods, then you could use:

```
my_method='pchip' #or 'linear' or 'spline'
interp = s.interpolate(method=my_method, order=2, limit=2, limit_direction='both')
```

Those methods are the ones I know of that would work in your case, but maybe there might be also more.

The parameter `limit` is specified as:

> Maximum number of consecutive NaNs to fill. Must be greater than 0.

And `limit_direction` is specified as:

> If limit is specified, consecutive NaNs will be filled in this direction.

More infos in [pandas.Series.interpolate docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)

Comment: Interesting, except for at 0, the spline method looks best, but at zero it give a negative number which is impossible. Is there a way to tell 'spline': lower boundary never less than value?

Comment: Sadly there is no direct way. One hacky way would be:
`val = 0 #the lower boundary`
`interp[interp<val]=val`